# Port Forwarding Behind 3 Routers

Tags: networking, router, internet, firewall, asus

I am trying to expose my elasticsearch service to the internet, but not having any luck. I updated the `network.host:` property to `0.0.0.0` and `discovery.seed_hosts` property to `[]` in the `elasticsearch.yml`. I've also setup a Window firewall rule to allow incoming connections. I am able to reach the elasticsearch service on localhost and within my network(192.168.1.x), but not from the internet.

My network setup is like this

Motorola Modem/Router(192.168.0.1) ---Ethernet--> Asus Router(192.168.0.2/192.168.1.1) ---Wireless---> Asus Router(192.168.1.60) ---Ethernet---> Elasticsearch service(192.168.1.12)

I have setup a `Virtual Server` rule on the `Motorola Modem/Router(192.168.0.1)` to route traffic to the `Elasticsearch service(192.168.1.12)` with `LAN Loopback` enabled. I also have the `Elasticsearch service(192.168.1.12)` setup as the `DMZ Host IP Address`.

I've also setup an `Inbound Firewall Rule` in the `Asus Router(192.168.0.2/192.168.1.1)`. This only allows IPv6 addresses so I've added the IPv6 of the `Elasticsearch service(192.168.1.12)` here and put in the elasticsearch port.